# Can we not delete published Knowledge Articles?

Tags: permissions, knowledge

Can we not delete the Publish `Knowledge Article`?

I have given `Read`, `Create`, `Edit`, `Delete`, and `View All` permissions to the profile. But it looks like only Draft articles can be deleted. I cant see any option to delete published articles?

[image: Permissions]

Comment: Everything on this exchange is about Salesforce. You don't have to add it to your posts. It's redundant. Remember, it's the *Salesforce* Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete published article you need to archive the article.

Then from Archived Articles list, choose the article to delete.

[image: delete article]

Answer (score 1):

You can delete draft articles, draft translations of articles, or archived articles, but not published articles or translations.

Regarding you query: To delete published article and translations, first remove them from publication by choosing edit or archive.

for more information please check the below resource link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_delete.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact, I'm a sys admin and there doesn't seem to be a delete button in the Lightning UI. I've been trying to delete the test articles in our instance for way too long now. I opened a case with them and they suggested a screensharing session

**I finally accomplished it by switching to Classic UI, heading to Article Management, viewing archived articles and deleting.**

I suspect in order to do this in Lightning, you actually have to customize the knowledge tab in the service console to have a delete button.

Comment: Hi CIK, please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer]. The advice in this post seems useful. Please refrain, however, from asking questions in an `Answer` post, or your content will likely be flagged for deletion. I've gone ahead and made the recommended change here.